# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.core.cfg.DeprecatedGrailsConfig

Tags: grails, migration, grails3, grails-4

**I am migrating my project from grails 3 to grails 4. while doing a bootrun, I encounter the below error:
Not sure if it is some deprecated import or method instantiation**

The error also points out to a file where there is this line:

```
def restBuilder = new RestBuilder()   // import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.abc.AuditService]: Constructor threw exception;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/core/cfg/DeprecatedGrailsConfig
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1294)
        ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/core/cfg/DeprecatedGrailsConfig
        at org.grails.web.converters.configuration.ConvertersConfigurationInitializer.initJSONConfiguration(ConvertersConfigurationInitializer.java:82)
        at org.grails.web.converters.configuration.ConvertersConfigurationInitializer.initialize(ConvertersConfigurationInitializer.java:64)
        at grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder.<init>(RestBuilder.groovy:58)
        at grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder.<init>(RestBuilder.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:241)
        at org.abc.AuditService.<init>(AuditService.groovy:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
        ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.core.cfg.DeprecatedGrailsConfig
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 98 common frames omitted
```

Comment: "Not sure if it is some deprecated import or method instantiation"- It isn't a deprecated import and there is no such thing as method instantiation in Java.  The problem is a reference to a class that does not exist on your classpath (that class was deprecated at one point).   Which version of `RestBuilder` are you pulling into the app?  (not your question but FYI... there are better options than `RestBuilder` in recent versions of Grails).

Comment: using this:compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:5.0.0.RC2

Comment: Does `org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE` work for you?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown it works now after changing the plugin version! thanks a lotttt!! :)